# find the characteristic polynomial of $I_n +xy^*$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

let $x,y \in \mathbb C^n$ find the characteristic polynomial of $I_n +xy^*$.
I think we can use the relation $X^nP_{AB}(x)=X^mP_{BA}(X)$
we put $A=x$ and  $B=x^{-1}+y^*$ is this right?

Comment: What is $m$ here?

Comment: columns of matrix that is for all $M_{n,m}(\mathbb C)$

Comment: For Googling purposes, such a matrix will be a "rank-one update to the identity". More generally there's a number of formulas for how various quantities change when a matrix is subject to a rank-one perturbation, for instance the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).

Comment: Since x is a vector, x^{-1} is... what?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez $1/x$

Comment: And that is what, exactly?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  it's $(1/x_1,1/x_2...)$

Comment: And you are saying that AB is the same as I+x^{-1}y ?

Comment: No we have $AB= x(x^{-1}+y^*)= 1+xy^*=I_n+xy^*$

Comment: Have you actually computed that in an example — with n=2, say?

Comment: Actually NO But am i wrong ?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez We can replace $I_n$ with $ee^\top$ ?